# Compare two websites

Tags: web, version-control, comparison

I need to compare two sites say X and Y. Both X and Y are the same websites, but in Y we made some changes in a particular stage. So I need to verify the changes by comparing X and Y. Can you suggest some tools to identify the changes in my page?

Comment: How will you access those sites? From a browser, or internally through your network? If a program, then what OS? Price? What kind of changes do you want to detect? One page at a time, or the structure of the site as well? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for professional development, then your version control system should diff the files for you. If you have no version control, then shame on you ;-)

In any case, if the websites were remote, you could  use you could use [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to download them.

Since you say that you made changes, then I presume that you already have them locally. In which case, the answer is simple.

You can pay $60 for [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/), or use a free file-compare utility, such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), which will compare two directory trees, and tell you which files are the same, and which are different:

[image]

Then, for each file, you can compare the two versions and see the differences (even copy sections from one to the other):

[image]

I think that that will solve your problem (and, please, consider using version control in future ;-)